# Any examples of loading to BigQuery using a POST request and Java client library?

Tags: java, google-bigquery, client-library

Does anyone have any examples of creating a new insert job for BigQuery using both:

- the bigquery java client library
- creating a load job from a POST request documented here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#loaddatapostrequest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call the **[bigquery.jobs().insert(...)](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/Bigquery.Jobs.Insert.html)** method.

I don't know what you have done yet but you should have an authenticated client to the API at least like:

```
bigquery = new Bigquery.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credentials)
                .setApplicationName("...").build();
```

That's a simplified version of an insertRows method i wrote using the [google-http-client library for java](http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/) and the [bigquery-api](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#BigQuery_API) (you should check that the dataset exists, validate ids etc.):

```
public Long insertRows(String projectId, 
                       String datasetId, 
                       String tableId, 
                       InputStream schema,
                       AbstractInputStreamContent data) {
    try {

        // Defining table fields
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<TableFieldSchema> schemaFields = mapper.readValue(schema, new TypeReference<List<TableFieldSchema>>(){});
        TableSchema tableSchema = new TableSchema().setFields(schemaFields);

        // Table reference
        TableReference tableReference = new TableReference()
                .setProjectId(projectId)
                .setDatasetId(datasetId)
                .setTableId(tableId);

        // Load job configuration
        JobConfigurationLoad loadConfig = new JobConfigurationLoad()
                .setDestinationTable(tableReference)
                .setSchema(tableSchema)
                // Data in Json format (could be CSV)
                .setSourceFormat("NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON")
                // Table is created if it does not exists
                .setCreateDisposition("CREATE_IF_NEEDED")
                // Append data (not override data)
                .setWriteDisposition("WRITE_APPEND");
        // If your data are coming from Google Cloud Storage
        //.setSourceUris(...);

        // Load job
        Job loadJob = new Job()
                .setJobReference(
                        new JobReference()
                                .setJobId(Joiner.on("-").join("INSERT", projectId, datasetId,
                                        tableId, DateTime.now().toString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss-SSS")))
                                .setProjectId(projectId))
                .setConfiguration(new JobConfiguration().setLoad(loadConfig));
        // Job execution
        Job createTableJob = bigquery.jobs().insert(projectId, loadJob, data).execute();
        // If loading data from Google Cloud Storage
        //createTableJob = bigquery.jobs().insert(projectId, loadJob).execute();

        String jobId = createTableJob.getJobReference().getJobId();
        // Wait for job completion
        createTableJob = waitForJob(projectId, createTableJob);
        Long rowCount = createTableJob != null ? createTableJob.getStatistics().getLoad().getOutputRows() : 0l;
        log.info("{} rows inserted in table '{}' (dataset: '{}', project: '{}')", rowCount, tableId, datasetId, projectId);
        return rowCount;
    }
    catch (IOException e) { throw Throwables.propagate(e); }
}
```

I don't know the format of your data but if your are using files, you can add a function like:

```
 public Long insertRows(String projectId, String datasetId, String tableId, File schema, File data) {
    try {
        return insertRows(projectId, datasetId, tableId, new FileInputStream(schema),
                new FileContent(MediaType.OCTET_STREAM.toString(), data));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) { throw Throwables.propagate(e); }
}
```